# How can a fragment work as a dialog to show on the top of view

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dialog, fragment

i am doing somethings that i want to use fragment work as dialog which will always show on the top layer of view in the `getWindow.getDecorView`
But i have no idea how to do that.
I have a activity and a fragment and streaming sdk which will get the decor view to show on the
top of view. However, i want to add a fragment on the view.
The situation is like that.
for now i use dialog to solve the problems. but i want to use fragment instead

NOW:
Order of view Layer :

Activity <--attach-->Fragment A <-----> Streaming FrameLayout<------>  DialogA

i want to be like that:

Activity <--attach-->Fragment A <-----> Streaming FrameLayout<------>  FragmentB

***Update::::***

But if I just add the fragment on the activity it will show like that
Activity <--attach-->Fragment A <-----> FragmentB<----->Streaming FrameLayout

Comment: what is in the fragment?

Comment: the fragment will call the sdk and the sdk will invoke get the decor view and add the view on the topmost. Therefore, the streaming view will always cover the activity and fragment

Comment: yeah okay but what VIEW is it a video player, text view, edit text,The DecorView is the view that actually holds the window’s background drawable. Calling getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable() from your Activity changes the background of the window by changing the DecorView‘s background drawable, so what will be in that view?

Comment: using a fragment wont make much diffrence from using a dialog like you are already doing

Comment: the added view is a custom view by sdk  is extend by FrameLayout.

Comment: custom view for what? are you going to display text? or video? IMage?

Comment: https://github.com/voxeet/voxeet-uxkit-android/blob/master/uxkit/src/main/java/com/voxeet/uxkit/controllers/AbstractConferenceToolkitController.java
on line 282//

this is the view of the will be added when i call the sdk .

Comment: nah bruh just use a dialog